# Await.result is not waiting for Future in Map to be completed

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-kafka, future

I am trying to wait for a my Future block in map collection to be fulfilled however my tests are failing.

```
val kafka_topics = "A, B"
val fileNames = "fileA, fileB"
val kafka_topic = kafka_topics.split(",").map(_.trim)
val fileName = fileNames.split(",").map(_.trim)

/**
*  // Here I started getting error since I changed from 
* val future = Future.sequence {
*   Seq {
*       Future(compare(fileName, kafka_topic, directory)),
*       Future(compare(fileName, kafka_topic, directory))
*    } 
* }
* Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
*  // To this below code, and seems like it's not working as expected
*/
val future = Future { 
      kafka_topic.zip(fileName).map {
        case (kafka_topic, fileName) =>
          Future(compare(fileName, kafka_topic, directory))
      }
    }
    Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
}

private def compare(fileName: String, topicName: String, directory: String) Unit = {
    Eventually.eventually(timeout(Span(10, Seconds)), interval(Span(2, Seconds))) {
       val actualMessage = kafkaService.comsumingTopic(topicName) // consuming from Topic
       val expectedMessage = "Expected Message" // Expected meesage
       assertSingleElementOrListResults(expectedMessage, actualMessage)
    }
}
```

Could someone please suggest me how can I improve my Future in map collections?

Comment: Here, you found the problem: "Here I started getting error since I changed from". 
That's you answer: change it back! Your new code is wrong.

Comment: the number of topics and files are parameterised and if I hard code it then I have to write N number of line of code.

Comment: You have a future of a future, so you only await for the first future. Use `flatMap` instead of `map`

Answer (score 1):

Your new code is creating a list of `Future`s and returning it inside another `Future`. The `Await.result` is waiting for the outer `Future`, but is not waiting for any of the inner `Future`s in the list to complete. That is what `Future.sequence` does, so you need to retain that from your original code:

```
val future = Future.sequence { 
  kafka_topic.zip(fileName).map {
    case (kafka_topic, fileName) =>
      Future(compare(fileName, kafka_topic, directory))
  }
}
Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```

More generally, you should probably not wait like this but instead return the `Future` to the calling code or use `onComplete` to do something when the results are available.